# can not resolve symbol rewardedvideocall back in android studio

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I want to create callback of Appodeal In AppcompatActivity in android studio, but it give me an error
 ***can not resolve symbol rewardedvideocallback***
My Code is

```
 public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements     NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
{ 
 {
  @Override protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{  
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = 
   new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build(); 
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

  Appodeal.setRewardedVideoCallbacks(new RewardedVideoCallbacks() //***here error shown***
  {
  private Toast mToast;
  @Override
  public void onRewardedVideoLoaded() {
    showToast("onRewardedVideoLoaded");
  }
  @Override
  public void onRewardedVideoFailedToLoad() {
   showToast("onRewardedVideoFailedToLoad");
  }
  @Override
  public void onRewardedVideoShown() {
  showToast("onRewardedVideoShown");
  }
 @Override
  public void onRewardedVideoFinished(int amount, String name) {
  showToast(String.format("onRewardedVideoFinished. Reward: %d %s", amount, name));
}
 @Override
 public void onRewardedVideoClosed(boolean finished) {
showToast(String.format("onRewardedVideoClosed,  finished: %s",      finished));
}
void showToast(final String text) {
if (mToast == null) {
  mToast = Toast.makeText(mActivity, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
}
mToast.setText(text);
mToast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
mToast.show();
```

}
});

Comment: `RewardedVideoCallbacks` is not android API. relevant tags and description is using any SDK probably `ironsource-mobile`?

Comment: so can you help me @ρяσѕρєяK

Comment: check your imports as doc saying it is inside `import com.supersonic.mediationsdk.sdk.RewardedVideoListener;`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I am implementing Appodeal Ads, i can show appodeal.rewarded video but can not implement call back

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it while i write the code like this

```
Appodeal.setRewardedVideoCallbacks(new   
com.appodeal.ads.RewardedVideoCallbacks() 
{
 });
```

Just add this line com.appodeal.ads